# Crystal Report Database connection login failed

Tags: database-connection, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

I am using crystal report and trying to print an invoice. I am populating the crystal report through list of objects instead of database.But I am facing the crystal report database connection window. I need to bypass it.

[image: image description]

My code is as below:

```
                List<ReportHeader> RH = new List<ReportHeader>();
                RH.Add(new ReportHeader("212EE212", "000004", "Asghar", "2234", "Ahmad", "Nice Transaction", "2/25/2016", "16:45"));
                List<ReportDetail> RD = new List<ReportDetail>();
                RD.Add(new ReportDetail("inpironD610", 3, 35000, 105000));
                RD.Add(new ReportDetail("inpironD986", 3, 35000, 105000));
                List<ReportFooter> RF = new List<ReportFooter>();
                RF.Add(new ReportFooter(210000,4500,214500));
                ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
                InvoiceReport IR = new InvoiceReport();

                IR.SetDataSource(RH);
                IR.SetDataSource(RD);
                IR.SetDataSource(RF);

                IR.PrintToPrinter(1, true, 0, 0);
                InvoiceReportViewer.ReportSource = IR;
```

Comment: Where are the login details in the above code? Database credentials and username and password.

Comment: I am not adding the data from database so I guess i don't need any login credentials ..... do I ???

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/371018/Create-Crystal-Report-Document, check what you are doing different. Also view - http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/ReportViewerObject04172007111636AM/ReportViewerObject.aspx